# How to tell flatten-maven-plugin:1.0.1 leave ${project.basedir} not to resolve it with a fix string when produce flatten pom

Tags: maven, flatten-maven-plugin

I'm using flatten-maven-plugin:1.0.1 to solve my dependency versions.

But it introduces another problem.

In my pom I have using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cryptix</groupId>
    <artifactId>cryptix-jce-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/cryptix-jce-provider.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The flattened pom replaced the ${project.basedir} with fix string and it is not portable when other people using the flattened pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cryptix</groupId>
    <artifactId>cryptix-jce-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/dsd-content-store-springboot-   spring-consul/store-view-springboot/store-view-server/libs/cryptix-jce-provider.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Can you please let me know if I can configure the flatten-maven-plugin to leave the property alone and not resolved it.

Comment: Did you get this issue solved? Can you share the answer?

Comment: @RKajaMohideen No I did not find away to solved it. I just have to work around it.

Comment: We are experiencing this as well, even when the the use of ${project.basedir} is implicit, such as for profile activation using file existence. There are outstanding issues on the project in this area: https://github.com/mojohaus/flatten-maven-plugin/issues/149 and https://github.com/mojohaus/flatten-maven-plugin/issues/57